# How do I get detailed information on the cause of 500 error deploying aspnet core app to azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy an aspnet core app to azure and getting a 500 error.

These are the steps I have taken to try and resolve the issue.

**Publish Profile**
DEBUG

**Web Config**
customErrors mode="Off"

**Publish Steps**
Remove additional files at destination

**Portal Settings**

- Set environment variable to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
- Diagnostics Logs - All switched ON
- Streamed Logs
- Live HTTP traffic
- Application Events
- FREB logs

**Log Files Checked**

- Detailed Errors
- http- raw Logs
- Kudu - trace logs
- Web Server Logs
- Event logs
- stdout

This is a huge amount of data to trawl through when you dont know what you are looking for. In spite of all the advanced diagnostics tools, there is nothing I can find that helps in any way. There is nothing more than I can find to give the slightest clue as to the cause. Just the same old useless 500 error page.

I have completely deleted and redeployed the app 30+ times from the portal. I have restarted the app many more times from the portal.

I have posted on the Azure forums and there no help to be had there either. Other posts I have read are just guesses without any substantial information as to the cause.

Does anyone have a definitive method to find more detail to the cause?

Comment: Can you post the link to any existing thread you started for context?

Comment: Have you been able to deploy this app locally?

Comment: The app runs locally without any issues

Comment: Greg, did you ever sort this out? I'm having a similar issue and can't find any useful help anywhere about how to get information about what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the detailed error message under **D:\home\LogFiles\DetailedErrors** folder via Kudu. And you could see most likely causes from the error page, like this.

[image]

You could compare your error status code (it could be 500.0, 500.19 etc) with the 500 status codes table form [this link](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938) to find the possible causes.

Besides, you could try to turn on “**Remote debugging**” to check if it could step into your controller action code and if any error with your action code.

Comment: As I explained above, the 500 error page does not give any further detail. Also, with 500 errors, you cant step into controllers because the app hasn't even started.